# Is there an algorithm that can solve this variation of the Knapsack Problem?

Tags: knapsack-problem

I want to do a variation on the **0-1 knapsack** problem. Just like the original problem each item would have a weight and value, and you are minimizing weight and maximizing value. However each item would be part of a set e.g. `Book1(value, weight, set).`

I need an algorithm that can sort these, given an upper limit on each individual set. So for instance Set A would be `(Book1, Book2, Book3)` and I could only have 
**3 items from set A in the entire knapsack.**

There would be no limits on individual items, so I could take as many `Book1's` as I wished, but I couldn't take more than Set A would allow me to take. The entire knapsack would have multiple sets each with multiple items.

I've tried individually solving each set before solving the problem as a whole using the solutions from each set, but it gives me obviously suboptimal solutions.

How should I design my code so that it produces the best result?

Comment: You should be able to model this using the solver. see https://www.solver.com/partial-loading-knapsack-problem

Comment: Should be easy to model as an integer programming problem. Also, "so I could take as many Book1's as I wished, but I couldn't take more than Set A would allow me to take" seems contradictory (note the "could" followed almost instantly by "couldn't").